# physical address not available when changing mode from protected mode to x86-64

Tags: c, assembly, x86, operating-system, x86-64

Literally, I just stuck in the instruction which changes cr0 register.

Here's my code which does the transition from i386 to x86-64.

```
global switch64BitKernel

SECTION .text

switch64BitKernel:
    mov eax, cr4
    or eax, 0x20
    mov cr4, eax

    mov eax, 0x100000
    mov cr3, eax

    mov ecx, 0xC0000080
    rdmsr

    or eax, 0x0100
    wrmsr

    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0xE0000000
    xor eax, 0x60000000
    mov cr0, eax

    jmp 0x08:0x200000

    jmp $
```

0x100000 : PML4 Entry,
0x200000 : x86-64 code

This is the whole code : [os.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nyNK8zQYThk57lhAVuXqg6jSbjau9zAi)

And this is the error message from bochs debugger:

[image]

Comment: is the page containing the 32-bit code mapped?

Comment: @Margaret Bloom Yes, there's ```[BITS 32]``` on the code.

Comment: No, that's not my point. Paging takes effect immediately (as soon as you write `cr0`), so do you have a page mapping the code in`switch64BitKernel`? As you can see, bochs complains immediately after `mov cr0, eax`.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I just miscoded a gdt table...... thank you for your help